# How to update a neo4j graph database from an Elasticsearch with mimimal latency?

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a number of Elasticsearch indices which are updated on a regular basis, and I'd like to have these updates reflected in a Neo4j graph database, with a minimal delay between the indexing of the item in Elasticsearch and its being updated into Neo4j.

(Also it's important to have administrative work kept low: I'd just want to update a cypher statement to define the mapping between the index documents and the graph, for example, so that once I've created an index, it's limited work to have its data added to Neo4j).

Is it possible to do this using Elastic search [watchers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-getting-started.html) and [triggers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-webhook.html)? Or by some other means?

I'm aware of the APOC library's [Elasticsearch functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/4.0/database-integration/elasticsearch/) in Neo4j, but I'd rather push from Elasticsearch on update than pull from Neo4j. GraphAware also has an [extension](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch), but it seems aimed mostly at the Neo4j to ES direction.

Comment: Have you tried out Logstash with the Neo4j JDBC driver? That would probably be the first place i might look.

Comment: Thanks. Not yet. I'll try it though, once time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch triggers can post a HTTP request and Neo4j has a HTTP Api, so that seems doable: https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/

If I were to do this in production I would probably develop a microservice that listens to the webhooks and stores the data into Neo4j. This way you can introduce retry policy as well as log errors if nothing else.

After doing a bit of research you could configure the ElasticSearch to push updates to Kafka with tools such as https://github.com/malike/elasticsearch-kafka-watch, and then ingest the data with the [Neo4j Kafka Sink](https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/).

Comment: Thanks: I'll try a basic microservice to test the principle. I'm not familiar with Kafka, but will have a look.

Comment: ...for the moment, I've got this working using a basic microservice and the Neo4j APOC library, which has functions for extracting data from Elastic Search (see https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/database-integration/elasticsearch/). The microservice submits cypher which calls apoc.es.query (see under "8.3.2.1. Pagination"), and can be triggered immediately after the job which updates Elastic Search. Draft code at https://github.com/phhu/es-to-neo4j